# Calling a previously written method and using this method to calculate the differences of array elements untill all elements are equal

Tags: java, arrays, loops, methods

I wrote a method called differences, which calculates the difference of each element in an array. I now want to call that method and use it to calculate the differences of an array until all the elements are equal. I also wrote a method to tell me, when all the elements in an array are equal.

This is what my code looks like for the differences and `allEqual` methods. Where sequence is an input string which I split and turned into an array of doubles:

```
public double[] differences ()
 {
   int length =  sequence.length-1;
   double[] differences = new double[length];
   for ( int i = 0; i<length; i++) {
       differences[i] = sequence[i+1] - sequence[i];
   }
   return differences;
 }


 public boolean allEqual() 
 { 
   for ( int i=1; i<sequence.length; i++) {
   if ( sequence[i]!=sequence[i-1]){
      return false;
   }}

   return true;
   }
```

I know I need to use a loop. But I'm not sure how to call these two methods and when to call them.

Comment: Try something at least.

Comment: I do not really understand your question. You are nowhere modifying 'sequence'. So how should the elements become equal? To what value should all elements become equal to?

Comment: @HajoLemcke I guess the loop to implement must replace the initial sequence by the computed difference, and continue util all the elements are equal. In the end, in the worst case, since one element is removed at each step, it will converge to an array of size 1.

Comment: with allEqual i am just using that to check if the elements in sequence are all the same. I am not changing the elements. I then want to use that method to stop a loop which will continuosly calculate the difference of an array until all the elements are equal. Im just not sure how i call these two methods.

Comment: @HaM551 do you realize that what you're describing is an infinite loop: "Let's compute the difference of 5, 3 and 0. Damn! All elements are not equal. So let's try again. Let's compute the difference of 5, 3 and 0. Damn! All elements are not equal. So let's try again. Let's compute the difference of 5, 3 and 0. Damn! All elements are not equal. So let's try again..."

Comment: Um, from my understanding, wouldnt that give (3-5 = -2)  ( 0+2) = {2}, so it would leave you with an array of one lement, in which case all elements are equal.

Comment: You said "I then want to use that method to stop a loop which will continuosly calculate the difference of an array until all the elements are equal.". If you want that to happen, this loop will have to change the array. Try something, and come back if you have a concrete question.

Comment: how would i call the two methods, differences() and alllEqual() ?

Comment: when does the array get changed if you keep calling allEquals() and differences() nothing will change (if they are not equal for ex) post more code on how you fill the array `sequences` and what changes have to be done to make them equals, you may also want to consider passing parameters to the method instead of using global scope array